# Scope of a lambda function when passed to another module

Tags: python, lambda, scope

I'm trying to wrap my head around the scope of Lambda functions.  I noticed that I can create a lambda function in one module **A** and pass it to a function in another module **B**, but able to call functions from module **A** .

Is this bad practice to pass lambda functions around like this, or is there a more preferred (Best Practice) method for handling this?

*target.py*

```py
class TestLambda():

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

    def call(self,func):
        func(self.name)
```

*source.py*

```py
from target import TestLambda

def sayHello(name):
    print("Hello {}".format(name))

func = lambda n: sayHello(n)

l = TestLambda("John")
l.call(func)
```

**output**

```
➜  lambda-test python3 source.py
Hello John
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a lambda "function"; a lambda *expression* is just one way to create a `function` object. There is no meaningful difference between `func = lambda n: sayHello(n)` and `def func(n): return sayHello(n)`.

Comment: You are not passing around `func` between modules at all though.  `TestLamda` class was already imported into your `source.py` name space.  You are just passing `func` as a parameter to your `TestLambda.call` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is that every `function` object keeps a reference to the scope in which the function was *defined*.

```
>>> func.__globals__['sayHello']
<function sayHello at 0x1085f2680>
```

This is what lets `func` still call `sayHello` even when called from a function with a different global scope. Name lookups are *static*; they depend only on the lexical (static) context in which the names appear, not the runtime (dynamic) context. There are languages (Lisp, shell, etc) that use dynamic scoping; lexical or static scoping is widely regarded as easier to reason about, though.

Comment: Thanks for this - I actually had the wrong concept and thought `sayHello()` was only referenced because it's within the same namespace.  Interesting to know that each function keeps their own reference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any issues with creating and passing lambda functions around, as opposed to using

`def func(name):`

but I don't see the point in defining a function as a lambda expression if you are going to use it in a different module.

The result is the same, the only difference is that you're not consistent with your function definitions.

[The Python docs specifically discourage this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations):

> Always use a def statement instead of an assignment statement that
>   binds a lambda expression directly to an identifier.
>
> Yes:
>
> `def f(x): return 2*x`
>
> No:
>
> `f = lambda x: 2*x`
>
> The first form means that the name of the resulting
>   function object is specifically 'f' instead of the generic ''.
>   This is more useful for tracebacks and string representations in
>   general. The use of the assignment statement eliminates the sole
>   benefit a lambda expression can offer over an explicit def statement
>   (i.e. that it can be embedded inside a larger expression)